# getting CLOCK_TICK_RATE value in linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to print the value of CLOCK_TICK_RATE with the following program:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/kd.h>
#include <linux/timex.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n",CLOCK_TICK_RATE);
}
```

I get an compilation error:

error: ‘CLOCK_TICK_RATE’ undeclared.

I looked for the definition of CLOCK_TICK_RATE, I found that in timex.h, but even after I included timex.h CLOCK_TICK_RATE is still undeclared.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add more information to your question: Which Kernel version? Which architecture?

Comment: AFAIK `CLOCK_TICK_RATE` is not defined in headers on a newer Linux system. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    printf (
        "%ld\n", 
        sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

It's in hertz and is normally 100.